# Express.js sendfile() vs. render()

Tags: node.js, express

I tried both `res.render('index.html')` and `res.sendfile('index.html')` and they both seem to be doing the same thing. I don't find the Express.js documentation very helpful.

What's the difference between the two?

Comment: Take a look at Express API documentation: https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.render   and    https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.sendFile

Answer (score 161, accepted):

The `render` method works when you have a templating engine, such as [Handlebars](https://handlebarsjs.com) or [Jade](http://jade-lang.com), in use.

A templating engine is something that parses a given template file and generates HTML output. This is so you can generate an HTML web page depending on some variables in your program.

Such templates are often used with Express.js when writing applications that have a front-end.

The `sendfile` method, on the other hand, simply sends a given file to the client, regardless of the type and contents of the file.

Since you are using an HTML file, there is nothing particularly to be parsed by the templating engine. So, the output of `render` is same as that of `sendfile` (i.e., the HTML written in the file). Hence, both produce the same result.

Comment: Thanks for the concise explanation!

Comment: So which one do you think is better?

Comment: @SarthakHingankar
It is not that any option is better than another, each one will simply be used for a specific case, in case you have configured a template engine on your server you must use res.render, otherwise it will not have any different effect using any of both, but the most concise would be res.sendfile.