# Diference between sendFile('/index.html') and render('index') from Jade

Tags: html, node.js, templates, express, pug

I'm new in JS. I've found a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23875360/express-sendfile-vs-render) but in other sense. My question is: What is the diference or aventage of a template Jade on Express over sending row html as response. I mean: why I'd use a template Jade on Express:

```
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.get('/', function (request, response) {
   response.render('index');});
```

if I can send directly the html file as response:

```
app.get('/', function (request, response) {
   response.set('Content-Type', 'text/html');
   response.sendFile('/index.html');});
```

Why would I spend time and processing rendering and sending a Jade file insted of sending directly a html file.

Thank you!.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because by compiling Jade views on the fly with each request, you can augment the template with server-side values.

```
var jade = require('jade');
var html = jade.render('h1 #{someVar}', { someVar: 'Hi there!' });
console.log(html); // "<h1>Hi there!</h1>"
```

The resulting HTML would change based on the value of `someVar` at the time you render the template. If you're just sending down static HTML files, then you can't insert data into the template as conveniently. That said, with Angular and other front-end frameworks becoming so popular there's not as much need to augment templates on the server.

With the advent of single-page apps it often makes more sense to render all your jade templates ahead of time when you're compiling your app. Most people do this with [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com) or [Gulp](http://gulpjs.com).

Answer (score 1):

Jade templates allow you to create dynamic HTML. (e.g. you could use if statements inside Jade to render different HTML markup depending on some logic). Furthermore you could insert values from the server into the template (e.g. the current logged in user's name).

As opposed to static html files, where to have dynamic content you would need to use JavaScript, and to have access to server variables you'd need to send AJAX requests to the server and parse the responses.