# Express single response workaround

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, http, passport.js

I am stuck in a bit of a dilemma here where once my user logs in I want to redirect them to the dashbord page but also send their json details to my client side javascript. I know that there can only be one res. send /end/json in a response and that I can send dynamic data using view engines.The reason why I want to send data separately is because I do not merely want to render it but rather use the data in my client side JS so that I can use it later for sockets in a chat application. I have tried a lot of things from using continuous local variables to try and create a middleware or an automatic redirect. The problem is no matter what the res.json() is hard to embed in a middleware as the very moment it is called there is no scope for declaring a next or redirect. Here is what my code looks like for the login route:

```
    router.get(’/’, (req,res)=>{
    console.log(req.user._id);
    
    User.findOne({
    
        "_id": req.user._id
    
    }, function(err, foundUser) {
    
        if (err) {
    
            console.log(err);
    
            return res.status(500).json({
    
                ok: false,
    
                error: err
    
            });
    
        } else {
    
            console.log(foundUser); //THE ELEMENT IS FOUND
    
            return res.status(200).json({
    
                ok: true,
    
                data: foundUser
    
            });
    
        }
    });
    res.sendFile('chat.html', { root: path.join(__dirname, '../views/') });
    });
```

Comment: are you using tokens or session?, if `chat.html` doesn't need values you dont need load the user, if it does then use res.render and pass foundUser like your doing with `root`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Express.js sendfile() vs. render()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23875360/express-js-sendfile-vs-render)

Comment: sidenote, no point using `path.join` if you're going to use slashes, it should be `path.join(__dirname, '..', 'views')`

Comment: This is not a node.js or express problem. This is how HTTP and HTML works. The way to do it is to have your dashboard request the json data from your server

Answer (score 0):

you can make ajax request from your page to fetch the data you want and save it in your client side.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your `chat.html` page request the json data. This means you need two routes:

```
router.get(’/’, (req,res)=>{
    es.sendFile('chat.html', { root: path.join(__dirname, '../views/') });
});

router.get(’/myself’, (req,res)=>{ // I normally call this route "myself"
                                   // but you can call it anything you want
    console.log(req.user._id);
    
    User.findOne({
        "_id": req.user._id
    }, function(err, foundUser) {
    
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
    
            return res.status(500).json({
                ok: false,
                error: err
            });
    
        } else {
            console.log(foundUser); //THE ELEMENT IS FOUND
    
            return res.status(200).json({
                ok: true,
                data: foundUser
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Now you need your `chat.html` file to make a request for the new `/myself` data. There are various ways to do this but for modern browsers you can use [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch):

#### chat.html

```
<html>
<head>
    ... rest of your html head
    <script>
        fetch('/myself')
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(res => {
                if (res.ok === false) {
                    // Handle your error here, I'm just alerting it:
                    alert(res.error);
                }
                else {
                    let user = res.data;

                    // Now you can do anything with the user data
                    // in here. I'm just logging it:

                    console.log('user =', user);
                }
            });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    ... rest of your html code
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: hey, thanks for the reply and sry for getting back a bit late.This is exactly the kind of thing I have been trying,I want to give you an upvote but I don't have enough rep yet.I am a bit new to using separate client side and server side js.The problem with this approach is, I do not want the data for my html page byt for my client side js where I want to store it in a variable but after that I want to automatically redirect the user to the main chat thing, can I do it within fetch.